# Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object

Tags: java, android, runtime-error

```
package com.example.agriflex.ui.fooddetail;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.icu.util.IslamicCalendar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.andremion.counterfab.CounterFab;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.cepheuen.elegantnumberbutton.view.ElegantNumberButton;
import com.example.agriflex.Common.Common;
import com.example.agriflex.Model.CommentModel;
import com.example.agriflex.Model.FoodModel;
import com.example.agriflex.Model.SizeModel;
import com.example.agriflex.R;
import com.example.agriflex.ui.comments.CommentFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ServerValue;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;
import butterknife.Unbinder;
import dmax.dialog.SpotsDialog;

public class FoodDetailFragment extends Fragment {

    private FoodDetailViewModel foodDetailViewModel;

    private Unbinder unbinder;
    private android.app.AlertDialog waitingDialog;

    @BindView(R.id.img_food)
    ImageView img_food;
    @BindView(R.id.btnCart)
    CounterFab btnCart;
    @BindView(R.id.btn_rating)
    FloatingActionButton btn_rating;
    @BindView(R.id.food_name)
    TextView food_name;
    @BindView(R.id.food_description)
    TextView food_description;
    @BindView(R.id.food_price)
    TextView food_price;
    @BindView(R.id.number_button)
    ElegantNumberButton numberButton;
    @BindView(R.id.ratingBar)
    RatingBar ratingBar;
    @BindView(R.id.btnShowComment)
    Button btnShowComment;
    @BindView(R.id.rdi_group_size)
    RadioGroup rdi_group_size;

    @OnClick(R.id.btn_rating)
    void onRatingButtonClick() {
        showDialogRating();
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.btnShowComment)
    void onShowCommentButtonClick() {
        CommentFragment commentFragment = CommentFragment.getInstance();
        commentFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "CommentFragment");
    }

    private void showDialogRating() {
        androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        builder.setTitle("Rating Food");
        builder.setMessage("Please fill Information");

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_rating, null);

        RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rating_bar);
        EditText edt_comment = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.edt_comment);

        builder.setView(itemView);

        builder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", (dialogInterface, i) -> {
            dialogInterface.dismiss();
        });
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", (dialogInterface, i) -> {
            CommentModel commentModel = new CommentModel();
            commentModel.setName(Common.currentUser.getName());
            commentModel.setUid(Common.currentUser.getUid());
            commentModel.setComment(edt_comment.getText().toString());
            commentModel.setRatingValue(ratingBar.getRating());
            Map<String, Object> serverTimeStamp = new HashMap<>();
            serverTimeStamp.put("timeStamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
            commentModel.setCommentTimeStamp(serverTimeStamp);

            foodDetailViewModel.setCommentModel(commentModel);

        });

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();
    }

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        foodDetailViewModel =
                ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(FoodDetailViewModel.class);
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_food_detail, container, false);
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, root);
        initViews();
        foodDetailViewModel.getMutableLiveDataFood().observe(this, foodModel -> {
            displayInfo(foodModel);

        });
        foodDetailViewModel.getMutableLiveDataComment().observe(this, commentModel -> {
            submitRatingToFirebase(commentModel);
        });
        return root;
    }

    private void initViews() {
        waitingDialog = new SpotsDialog.Builder().setCancelable(false).setContext(getContext()).build();
    }

    private void submitRatingToFirebase(CommentModel commentModel) {
        waitingDialog.show();
        //First , we will submit to Comments ref
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference(Common.COMMENT_REF)
                .child(Common.selectedFood.getId())
                .push()
                .setValue(commentModel)
                .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        //After submit to CommentRef , we will update value aveger in food
                        addRatingToFood(commentModel.getRatingValue());

                    }
                    waitingDialog.dismiss();

                });
    }

    private void addRatingToFood(float ratingValue) {
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference(Common.CATEGORY_REF)
                .child(Common.CategorySelected.getMenu_id()) // Select Category
                .child("foods") // select array list 'foods' of this category
                .child(Common.selectedFood.getKey()) // Because food item is array list so key is index of arraylist
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            FoodModel foodModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(FoodModel.class);
                            foodModel.setKey(Common.selectedFood.getKey()); //Don't forget set it
                            //Apply rating
                            if (foodModel.getRatingValue() == null)
                                foodModel.setRatingValue(0d); // d = D lower case
                            if (foodModel.getRatingCount() == null)
                                foodModel.setRatingCount(0l); // l = L lower case, not 1 (number 1)
                            double sumRating = foodModel.getRatingValue() + ratingValue;
                            long ratingCount = foodModel.getRatingCount() + 1;
                            double result = sumRating / ratingCount;

                            Map<String, Object> updateData = new HashMap<>();
                            updateData.put("ratingValue", result);
                            updateData.put("ratingCount", ratingCount);

                            //update data in variable
                            foodModel.setRatingValue(result);
                            foodModel.setRatingCount(ratingCount);

                            dataSnapshot.getRef()
                                    .updateChildren(updateData)
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                                        waitingDialog.dismiss();
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Thank you !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            Common.selectedFood = foodModel;
                                            foodDetailViewModel.setFoodModel(foodModel); // Call refresh
                                        }

                                    });

                        } else
                            waitingDialog.dismiss();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        waitingDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "" + databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
    }

    private void displayInfo(FoodModel foodModel) {
        Glide.with(getContext()).load(foodModel.getImage()).into(img_food);
        food_name.setText(new StringBuilder(foodModel.getName()));
        food_description.setText(new StringBuilder(foodModel.getDescription()));
        food_price.setText(new StringBuilder(foodModel.getPrice().toString()));

        if (foodModel.getRatingValue() != null)
            ratingBar.setRating(foodModel.getRatingValue().floatValue());

        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity())
                .getSupportActionBar()
                .setTitle(Common.selectedFood.getName());

        //Size
        for (SizeModel sizeModel: Common.selectedFood.getSizeModel())
            {
                RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(getContext());
                radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
                    if (isChecked)
                        Common.selectedFood.setUserSelectedSize(sizeModel);
                    calculateTotalPrice(); //Update Price
                });

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        1.0f);
                radioButton.setLayoutParams(params);
                radioButton.setText(sizeModel.getName());
                radioButton.setTag(sizeModel.getPrice());

                rdi_group_size.addView(radioButton);

            }

            if (rdi_group_size.getChildCount() > 0) {
                RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) rdi_group_size.getChildAt(0);
                radioButton.setChecked(true);  //Default First Select
            }

            calculateTotalPrice();

        }

        private void calculateTotalPrice () {
            double totalPrice = Double.parseDouble(Common.selectedFood.getPrice().toString()), displayPrice = 0.0;
            //Size
            totalPrice += Double.parseDouble(Common.selectedFood.getUserSelectedSize().getPrice().toString());

            displayPrice = totalPrice * (Integer.parseInt(numberButton.getNumber()));
            displayPrice = Math.round(displayPrice * 100.0 / 100.0);

            food_price.setText(new StringBuilder("").append(Common.formatPrice(displayPrice)).toString());
        }
    }
```

```
    ----------
    ## Heading ##

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.agriflex, PID: 5673
```

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.agriflex.ui.fooddetail.FoodDetailFragment.displayInfo(FoodDetailFragment.java:236)
    at com.example.agriflex.ui.fooddetail.FoodDetailFragment.lambda$onCreateView$2$FoodDetailFragment(FoodDetailFragment.java:135)
    at com.example.agriflex.ui.fooddetail.-$$Lambda$FoodDetailFragment$qUbisKr6hIzCwm4MXSIKgBZ3EXA.onChanged(Unknown Source:4)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:113)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:126)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$ObserverWrapper.activeStateChanged(LiveData.java:424)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$LifecycleBoundObserver.onStateChanged(LiveData.java:376)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:361)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.forwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:300)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:339)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:145)
    at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:131)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2637)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:915)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2100)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1874)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1830)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

I/zygote: Do full code cache collection, code=495KB, data=334KB
    After code cache collection, code=484KB, data=293KB

Comment: Please help me to solve this above runtime-error

Comment: You can use Java Exceptions - Try...Catch block after declaring List.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `displayInfo` method with

```
    private void displayInfo(FoodModel foodModel) {
        Glide.with(getContext()).load(foodModel.getImage()).into(img_food);
        food_name.setText(new StringBuilder(foodModel.getName()));
        food_description.setText(new StringBuilder(foodModel.getDescription()));
        food_price.setText(new StringBuilder(foodModel.getPrice().toString()));

        if (foodModel.getRatingValue() != null)
            ratingBar.setRating(foodModel.getRatingValue().floatValue());

        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity())
                .getSupportActionBar()
                .setTitle(Common.selectedFood.getName());

        //Size
        //Add NULL check for your object and your code wont throw the exception
        if(null!=Common.selectedFood && null!=Common.selectedFood.getSizeModel()) {

            for (SizeModel sizeModel : Common.selectedFood.getSizeModel()) {
                RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton(getContext());
                radioButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
                    if (isChecked)
                        Common.selectedFood.setUserSelectedSize(sizeModel);
                    calculateTotalPrice(); //Update Price
                });

                LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        1.0f);
                radioButton.setLayoutParams(params);
                radioButton.setText(sizeModel.getName());
                radioButton.setTag(sizeModel.getPrice());

                rdi_group_size.addView(radioButton);

            }
        }
        if (rdi_group_size.getChildCount() > 0) {
            RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) rdi_group_size.getChildAt(0);
            radioButton.setChecked(true);  //Default First Select
        }

        calculateTotalPrice();

    }
```

I have just added null checks before the list iteration.

Comment: Same problem Brother i am unable to solve it.Please help me

Comment: you are still getting nullpointerexception ? @SumithvarmaMarri

Comment: yes Brother i am still getting

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your "foodModel" is null:

```
foodDetailViewModel.getMutableLiveDataFood().observe(this, foodModel -> {
            displayInfo(foodModel);
 });
```

Before displaying info you need to check if is not null :

```
foodDetailViewModel.getMutableLiveDataFood().observe(this, foodModel -> {
      if( foodModel != null )
         displayInfo(foodModel);
 });
```

Otherwhise you need to check your "getMutableLiveDataFood()" method returns null data

Comment: Brother after changing the above i got new errors

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Long com.example.agriflex.Model.SizeModel.getPrice()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.agriflex.ui.fooddetail.FoodDetailFragment.calculateTotalPrice(FoodDetailFragment.java:271)
        at com.example.agriflex.ui.fooddetail.FoodDetailFragment.displayInfo(FoodDetailFragment.java:264)
        at com.example.agriflex.ui.fooddetail.FoodDetailFragment.lambda$onCreateView$2$FoodDetailFragment(FoodDetailFragment.java:136)

Comment: Please help Me to solve

Comment: It seems that in our loop " for (SizeModel sizeModel: Common.selectedFood.getSizeModel())" the "sizeModel" is null, simply add a "if(sizeModel != null) condition before do work on the radio button

Comment: i changed  if( foodModel != null ) to if(  foodModel == null  ) i got output without errors but i am not getting the radio button